# Exponential generating function of the sequence $1,0,1,0,\dots$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I'm currently learning [exponential generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_(EGF)) and am working on a problem that needs me to find the corresponding closed form expression to a given sequence.

I've been given the sequence $1,0,1,0,...$ and decided to use the EGF $e^x$ to find my solution by substituting $0$ in every odd term in the expression:

$e^x = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{x^r}{r!} = 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ...$

Doing so, I've arrived at this expression:

$1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + ...$

But I don't know where to go from here. Am I on the right track or is there a better way to find the closed form expression?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint: What is $e^{-x}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Taylor_series_expressions

Comment: Your expression is $\cosh x = \dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}2$

Comment: Exploiting even-oddness is definitely the way to go, but what you tried isn't "legal", so to speak. You can't substitute only **some** instances of a variables in an expression; you either substitute them all or none of them. Instead, consider what you get if you substitute $-x$ for $x$. Is there any symmetry you notice about the result? Can it be combined somehow with $e^x$ to get what you want?

Comment: @H.sapiensrex ah okay, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Have you considered $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$.

ETA: And that is basically all there is. Let $(a_i)_{i=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence. Then the exponential generating function $f$ for this sequence is *by definition* the function whose Taylor series is prescribed by $f(x) =$ $a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_ix^i}{i!}$. If the sequence is $1,0,1,0,\ldots$ where every other term is $1$ and the remaining terms are $0$, or equivalently, if the generating sequence is $(a_i)_{i=0}^{\infty}$, where $a_i$ is $1$ iff $i$ is even and is $0$ otherwise, then by definition of exponential generating function is $f(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$, as this function has the Taylor series expansion $f(x)=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_ix^i}{i!}$, where $a_i$ is $1$ iff $i$ is even, and $a_i =0$ otherwise.

Comment: I am curious...what is wrong with this answer? It addresses the OP's question...

Comment: +1 but WTF does ETA mean?

Comment: **E**dited **T**o **A**dd

Answer (score 1):

A few different ways to approach this one. For your sequence:
\begin{equation}
S = 1, 0, 1,0\dots
\end{equation}
If we let $T_n$ be the $n$-th value of $S$ with $T_0 = 1$, then we can define $S$ via the iterative sequence:
\begin{equation}
T_{n+ 1} = T_{n} + \left(-1\right)^{n + 1}
\end{equation}
Let us know define our Exponential Generating Function:
\begin{equation}
T\left(x\right) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty T_n \frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{equation}
We now return to our iterative sequence and multiply both sides by $\frac{x^n}{n!}$:
\begin{equation}
T_{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n!} = T_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!} + \left(-1\right)^{n +1}\frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{equation}
We now take the summation for $n \geq 0$:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty T_{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty T_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!} - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty\left(-1\right)^n\frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{equation}
Starting with the RHS:
\begin{equation} 
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty T_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!} = T\left(x\right); \qquad \qquad \sum_{n = 0}^\infty\left(-1\right)^n\frac{x^n}{n!}  = e^{-x}
\end{equation}
For the LHS, we evaluate by taking the derivative of $T(x)$ w.r.t. $x$:
\begin{equation}
T'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty T_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!}= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty T_{n}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^n\right]}{n!} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty T_{n}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty T_{n}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}   = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty T_{n}\frac{x^{n-1}}{\left(n-1\right)!}
\end{equation}
Shifting the index to $ m = n - 1$ we yield:
\begin{equation}
T'(x) =\sum_{m=0}^\infty T_{m + 1}\frac{x^{m}}{m!}
\end{equation}
And so, we arrive at:
\begin{equation}
T'(x) = T(x) - e^{-x} \longrightarrow T'(x) - T(x) = -e^{-x}
\end{equation}
Here we solve via the Integrating Factor:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{-x}T(x)\right] = -e^{-2x} \longrightarrow e^{-x}T(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-2x} + C \longrightarrow T(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x} + Ce^{x}
\end{equation}
Where $C = $ Constant of Integration. To resolve $C$ evaluate:
\begin{equation}
T(0) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty T_n \frac{0^n}{n!} = T_0 = 1
\end{equation}
And so,
\begin{equation}
T(0) = 1 = \frac{1}{2}e^{-0} + Ce^{0} = \frac{1}{2} + C \longrightarrow C =\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
Thus, we arrive at our Exponential Generating Function:
\begin{equation}
T(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x} + \frac{1}{2}e^{x} = \cosh(x)
\end{equation}

Comment: OP's sequence is $1,0,1,0,...$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner - Ta. I'll make the adjustments now.